Deploying to azure agent virtual machine - yml question
I'm struggling to create YML file which will simply copy build artifacts (of my ASP.NET MVC app) to c:/samplefolder on my virtual machine (Azure Agent). Can anyone help me with that please?
Everywhere I have searched there was some "pool" and "pool-name" needed, but I don't have any pool:

Or there were some examples with stages, tasks, but I cannot use them since it's one YML file.

Based on the limited information that we could see form the screenshot, your VM was added into a pipeline environment as a VM resource, which should be referenced by the environment properties of deployment jobs in a YAML pipeline rather than referenced by any pool name, though it did generate a new deployment pool with the corresponding environment id.

Assuming your YAML pipeline was building your app on a Microsoft-hosted windows-latest agent and had been publishing pipeline artifacts (drop in my case), you may use a deployment job in downstream stage (CD) to scale out deployment onto all those VMs with web and app tags. All available artifacts from the current pipeline (downloaded to $(Pipeline.Workspace)/<artifact name>) and from the associated pipeline resources are automatically downloaded in deployment jobs and made available for your deployment. Please take a look at the - deployment: DeployToMyVM job in the sample YAML pipeline definition below.
stages:
- stage: CI
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    displayName: Build App
    variables:
      BuildPlatform: 'any cpu'
      BuildConfiguration: 'release'
    steps:
    - powershell: |
       Write-Host "Just to represent the steps to build your .NET framework app, even though the steps were irrelevant to the query in this post" 
    - publish: $(PathToTheArtifactsFileThatWasBuilt)
      artifact: drop

- stage: CD
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployToMyVM
    environment:
      name: MyVm
      tags: app,web
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - powershell: |
              tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) /f /a
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            inputs:
              SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
              Contents: '**'
              TargetFolder: 'C:\samplefolder'
              CleanTargetFolder: true


See more details in the following documents.
Create and target environments - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn
Deployment jobs - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn
Automatic download in deployment jobs

The thing is, that its an .NET Framework app, not .NET Core app.

@guidempty, I should have known you would say so and shared a CI stage to build a .NET framework app demo. However, if you took a further look at my answer, you should understand the issue was not related to what app was built. Please pay attention to the CD stage, try and get to know how you could run the tasks across the VM resource(s) in an environment during a deployment job.

Thank You. I will check that and try to make it work in my case.
